# How to run something after every step in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'd like to check something after every step in a test case in Robot Framework. I am including a dummy example to represent what I am referring for:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Order From Somewhere
    [Tags]  whatever tags here
    Step1
    #Grab Exception
    Step2
    #Grab Exception
    Step3
    #Grab Exception
    Step4
    #Grab Exception
    Step5
    #Grab Exception
    Step6
    #Grab Exception
    Step7
```

I assume there is some way to have '#Grab Exception' executed after every Step, but in a nice way.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What is it that you want to run? Another keyword, or a python function? What does this function do?

Comment: I'd like to check if the URL contains a specific string (whether it's a Python or another keyword)
- if yes, continue
- if not, I want the 'Order From Somewhere' test case to fail

Comment: What is "the URL"? Is it a variable inside the test case? Is it a global variable? Is it a static string?

Comment: The URL is always the current browser window URL.
I could solve it with the first commented solution, and I was using the 'Location Should Contain' keyword in it.
Thanks for the questions anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own keyword to do that, for example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Special Keywords
    Special Keyword    Sleep    5 seconds
    Special Keyword    Log    <b>This is another keyword</b>    HTML

*** Keywords ***
Special Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${kw}    @{arguments}
    Run Keyword    ${kw}    @{arguments}
    Grab Exception

Grab Exception
    Log    Called <i>Grab Exception</i>    HTML
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a working solution and now I understand the way it works.

So just to clarify, the "Special Keyword" must be added to the beginning of each line where you want to test your exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like below in your settings area with Test Teardown option:

```
Run Keyword If Test Failed or Passed <name of the kw>
```

--- you can use one of it pass or fail OR you can use Unless a condition met.
e.g. as below:

```
    *** Settings ***
Test Setup       Open Application    App A
Test Teardown    Close Application

*** Test Cases ***
Default values
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown from setting section
    Do Something

Overridden setup
    [Documentation]    Own setup, teardown from setting section
    [Setup]    Open Application    App B
    Do Something

No teardown
    [Documentation]    Default setup, no teardown at all
    Do Something
    [Teardown]

No teardown 2
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown can be disabled also with special value NONE
    Do Something
    [Teardown]    NONE

Using variables
    [Documentation]    Setup and teardown specified using variables
    [Setup]    ${SETUP}
    Do Something
    [Teardown]    ${TEARDOWN}
```

Refer more at - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown